# how to fetch the picklist and field values dynamically from multiple objects

Tags: apex, schema

```
public class PickListController
{


global static list<SelectOption> getPicklistValues ('Employee__c' , 'Priority__c')
{
    list<SelectOption> options = new list<SelectOption>();

    // Get the object type of the SObject.
    Schema.sObjectType objType = obj.getSObjectType();

     // Describe the SObject using its object type.
     Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe = objType.getDescribe();   

     // Get a map of fields for the SObject
     map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objDescribe.fields.getMap(); 

     // Get the list of picklist values for this field.
     list<Schema.PicklistEntry> values =
     fieldMap.get(fld).getDescribe().getPickListValues();

     // Add these values to the selectoption list.
     for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : values)
     { 
        options.add(new SelectOption(a.getLabel(), a.getValue())); 
     }
     return options;
   }
 }
```

Comment: any issue with your code?

Comment: Unknown property 'PickListController.Employee__c'

Answer (score 0):

```
global static list<SelectOption> getPicklistValues(SObject obj, String fld){
    list<SelectOption> options = new list<SelectOption>();

    // Get the object type of the SObject.
    Schema.sObjectType objType = obj.getSObjectType();

     // Describe the SObject using its object type.
     Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe = objType.getDescribe();   

     // Get a map of fields for the SObject
     map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objDescribe.fields.getMap(); 

     // Get the list of picklist values for this field.
     list<Schema.PicklistEntry> values =
     fieldMap.get(fld).getDescribe().getPickListValues();

     // Add these values to the selectoption list.
     for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : values)
     { 
        options.add(new SelectOption(a.getLabel(), a.getValue())); 
     }
     return options;
   }
 }
```

---

**Edit**

```
public class PickListController
{

public PickListController(){
   list<SelectOption> lst = PickListController.getPicklistValues('Employee__c' , 'Priority__c'); 
   system.debug('=============check you picklist value here====='+lst);
}
public static list<SelectOption> getPicklistValues (SObject obj, String fld)
{
    list<SelectOption> options = new list<SelectOption>();

    // Get the object type of the SObject.
    Schema.sObjectType objType = obj.getSObjectType();

     // Describe the SObject using its object type.
     Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe = objType.getDescribe();   

     // Get a map of fields for the SObject
     map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objDescribe.fields.getMap(); 

     // Get the list of picklist values for this field.
     list<Schema.PicklistEntry> values =
     fieldMap.get(fld).getDescribe().getPickListValues();

     // Add these values to the selectoption list.
     for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : values)
     { 
        options.add(new SelectOption(a.getLabel(), a.getValue())); 
     }
     return options;
   }
 }
```

Here is a utility method which i use to fetch picklist value. Use this , pass object name , field name to fetch the values.

Comment: how to fetch the filed value dynamically

Comment: just pass object and field name. it will give you value. this is dynamic.

Comment: i didnt find the field name in ur code

Comment: `String fld` i am passing this as parameter and using it in code.

Comment: my filed name is email so in need to pass like String Email ??

Comment: email is picklist field? if yes then  pass `(objectname, 'email__c')\\ field API name`

Comment: no its a text filed

Comment: how to display on visualforce page

Comment: you can use `apex:selectlist` to display it on VF page.

Comment: global static list<SelectOption> getPicklistValues(Employee__c , 'Priority__c'){ //error unexpected token: ','

Comment: getPicklistValues('Employee__c' , 'Priority__c')

Comment: expecting a right parentheses, found 'Employee__c'

Comment: @keerthanachowdhary change your method to `getPicklistValues(SObject obj, String fld)` and whenever you want any value just call like `list<SelectOption> lst = PickListController.getPicklistValues('Employee__c' , 'Priority__c'); system.debug(lst);`  check debug here

Comment: @keerthanachowdhary check above ans edit